# Which users viewed a specific page in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I know you can't use the GA User ID as a Dimension, but I'm wondering if there's a report to find out which users viewed a specific page in GA. In other words, given a specific page path, which users viewed that page within a specific time range?

Answer (score 0):

You can find navigation of each Analytics user in the User Explorer report.

However, you can't get what you say unless you pass the clientId (GA User ID) in a custom dimension with user scope.

Comment: Yea, definitely see that in User Explorer, but I don't want to have to pull the history for every user just to see if they visited a specific page.

Comment: To do it you have to follow my suggest about custom dimension.